# Conditional formatting in Google Sheets is recognizing some cell values that equal 0, not others

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have two columns in my sheet where I would to use conditional formatting. I'd like the cells to

- be turned green when the value = 0
- be red when the value != 0.

Here's how I have the conditional formatting set up:

- Value is equal to 0 --> color green
- Value is not equal to 0 --> color red

**See screenshot** [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEdEY.png)

The output does not consistently color the cells correctly.

- Green cells only have 0 value (this is expected)
- But sometimes red cells have 0 value (this is unexpected)

**See screenshot** [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbseM.png)

Any tips on how to fix this?

If it helps, the values of cells in these columns are computed from other cells.

- column X is =W2-AE2
- column Z is =Y2-(AE2-AF2)

Comment: We don't know what's in Col W, Y, AE or AF; nor do we know your data types or full underlying values for any of the involved columns (e.g., 0.0002 is not the same as 0, but with formatting, those extra place values would not be visible except in the formula bar). Consider sharing a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of it), as that is likely the only way for the volunteer contributors here to ascertain the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the precision of the calculation, especially if you work with days and hours in W, AE and AF. So try to round the results.

[ROUND()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440)

for instance

```
=round(___your formula____,6)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Rounding worked.